# Jmeter response as "invalid csrf token" for steps after login. cookie manager is successfully passing token to subsequent request

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter response as "invalid csrf token" for steps after login. cookie manager is successfully passing authorization token to subsequent request but getting CSRF taken issue.
There is _csrf value generated in response of login and I tried to pass in body of subsequent request but its not working

---

Answer (score 0):

If JMeter response is "invalid csrf token" it means that you failed to properly perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) of the CSRF token.

If JMeter response is "invalid csrf token" it means that you failed to properly perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) of the CSRF token.

---

You need to check all your request parameters:

- URL
- Headers
- Body

as the token might come as the Cookie but you need to pass it somewhere else, maybe as a [hidden input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp)

If you cannot detect it anywhere the easiest way is just [recording your test scenario](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) 2 times and compare resulting JMeter [.jmx test plans](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan). All the values which differ are a subject to correlation.

Comment: HOw to Pass 'hidden input'?...I can see _csrf in response of Login Step but don know where to pass in subsequent request(which is giving INvalid CSRF token)because there is no CSRF parameter in header nor in Body of subsequent request.Also body is in JSON format